# Error encountered writing to Kudu using Spark / Scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kudu

I'm trying to write data into Kudu from Spark and I'm getting this error

```
   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.decodeDictionaryIds(VectorizedColumnReader.java:296) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.readBatch(VectorizedColumnReader.java:174) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextBatch(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:230) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:137) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:105)
```

Code example:

```
df.write.options(Map("kudu.master"-> "ip:7051",
                     "kudu.table"-> "test_kudu")).mode("append").kudu
```

Used libraries:

```
org.apache.kudu:kudu-spark2_2.11:1.8.0  
org.apache.kudu:kudu-client:1.8.0
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the code snippets prior to the df.write?

Comment: @thebluephantom I found the problem. Before writing to kudu I used  a custom schema for parquet and when I tried to use that schema it broke.